# Connecting to localhost database phpMyAdmin using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a localhost database hosted by phpMyAdmin using C# language. This is the connection details I have set up:

```
string connection = "server=127.0.0.1; database=project;user=root; password=root01;";

OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(connection);

connect.Open();
```

But nothing works.. I don't get any data back using SELECT statements etc.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does connect.Open() succeed? Also why do you use OleDBConnection and not MySqlConnection??